# Why do I need to press C twice to copy in Mac MS Word 2011 and 2016?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft

I have had this issue for years with MS Word 2011. I upgraded to MS Word 2016 and am still having the same problem. I can only copy if I press command, then double press C while holding down command. Just pressing command-C does not add anything to my clipboard.

How can I fix this? This problem has continued to haunt me for years, even after I did a factory reset on my Macbook, have upgraded Mac OS X several times and also upgraded MS Office. Thanks for the help.

If I hold down command-C for a second, I only have to press it once. Regardless of how long I hold it down, I see the Edit menu in the filebar flash blue... even if it doesn't copy anything to the clipboard after the first (or sometimes even the second) button press.

Comment: This is a wild guess but will only take a minute to check. Open the keyboard viewer, from the menu bar or system prefs > keyboard >show keyboard, emoji... etc & check you don't have a dead-key. Normally dead-keys would be on the Option key. Try it & watch the dead-keys turn orange. Make sure the same isn't happening on Cmd.

Comment: No, neither command nor C is a dead key.

Comment: OK, next guess - make a new admin account on your Mac & test it in that, at default settings. See if it's some kind of 'personalisation' in a single User in Office.

Answer (score 3):

Please loot at this:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/often-have-to-cmd-c-twice-to-copy-mac-office/0a3060eb-d185-46df-943d-3ed89f447d25?auth=1

When I disabled the *three fingers drag*, the problem have solved.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and provide a summery of the solution offered at the website you link to?

Comment: I had never noticed it, but I can now confirm this problem indeed only occurs when using 3-finger drag! When highlighting using keyboard or press-down-on-track-pad-dragging the problem does not occur for me. Some (myself included) might find that to be a more acceptable workaround than switching off 3-finger drag.

Comment: Just a note that I have the CMD-C problem on my MacPro, no trackpad like a macbook. So not sure your comment @Ricardo is valid.